# Integration tests with specific SQL command for PostgreSQL database

Tags: spring, postgresql, unit-testing

I've got a service calling a repository which make some specific SQL command which are only available on PostgreSQL (like current_date & array_agg). I'd like to do some integration test for this repository. Usually you spawn a H2 database for this kind of integration tests, but it works only for standard sql not for specific SQL. Do you know a way to test my repository ? Should I spawn a Postgres SQL server for those tests or are there some kind of translator like postgres to h2 ? Or other way to avoid spawning a Postgres instance ?

Regards,
Blured.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an automatic test for non-standard PostgreSQL SQL syntax, your only good choice is to test against PostgreSQL. If you test against anything else, it will either fail, or you could not be certain that it works with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/postgres/), they're a great way to spawn infrastructure dependencies for integration testing. If you want to test PostgreSQL specific query, then there is no other way, but to run it against that database. Using testcontainers make it very easy to setup and tear down test database.